# Unable to see session data after refresh in Laravel 5

Tags: php, session, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to write the name of logged in user to my view. It is ok when i first logged in but if a refresh the page or click to an another link the session data disappears. How can i fix this ?

```
@if(Session::get('username'))
   Welcome
   <span>
      <a href="#">
         {!! Session::get('username'); !!}     
      </a>
   </span>
@else
   Welcome
   <span>
      <a href="#">
         Please Log in     
      </a>
   </span>
@endif
```

Comment: Maybe not suppressing errors and warnings and taking a look into the error log helps?

Comment: @Jost who said i am suppressing them ?

Comment: Let's assume you're using the 'file' session driver, is your storage/framework/session folder there and is it writeable? If it is, there's supposed to be some files there after putting stuff in your session. 

Also, if you're using the default auth system, you can just use \Auth::user() to retrieve the logged in user, you don't have to put it in the session manually. (http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/authentication#retrieving-the-authenticated-user)

Comment: @Tartar Sorry, probably misunderstood the `@` - thought it was PHP code.

Comment: Also, check how you're storing the 'username' in session. If you do Session::flash() it only survives one request and is then cleared - you need to use Session::put()

Comment: @KaloyanDoichinov Session::put()  works, thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How is username being stored? If you do Session::flash() it is only for one request and then it gets cleared - you need to use Session::put() to retain it.

Although you might also be able to use Auth::user() to get currently logged-in user information and could draw from there what you need as well.